# Why doesn't my new Amazon EC2 cluster volume size reflect the size I set in the launch options

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, amazon-ec2

When I create a new cr1.8xlarge instance on EC2 with a 100GB EBS storage, and run `df -h`, I only get about 6Gb of available storage on the root device. The instance is created using the Red Hat Linux 6.5 for Cluster Instances AMI (ami-3425be04).

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to know is documented here:  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/RootDeviceStorage.html

Read the section "Root Device Storage Usage Scenarios"

At steps 5 + 6:

> Check the size of the root device on the instance. The increased size of the root device is not apparent yet. This is because the file system does not recognize the increased size on the root device.
>
> Resize the file system.

If you're going to be making a lot of these instances, you might want to do this for a base/vanilla instance, and then save it as a new private AMI.  You can then use that to start new nodes in your cluster rather than the public one you're using.